# cakephp pagination controller

Tags: cakephp, pagination

what shoud i write in the controller to have pagiation 
this is my index

```
<?php foreach ($bien['Servicebien'] as $servicebien): ?>
                <tr> <td><?php echo $servicebien['dateServiceBienDu']; ?>
                    <td><?php echo $servicebien['dateServiceBien']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $servicebien['montantServiceBien']; ?></td>


                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php unset($servicebien); ?>
            </table> 
            <div>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(array('format' => __('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of {:count} total, starting on record {:start}, ending on {:end}'))); ?>
```

Paginator->prev('<< Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); 
 echo $this->Paginator->numbers(); 
 echo $this->Paginator->next(' Next >> ', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); 
?>

Answer (score 0):

$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('model_name');

$this->set('data', $data);

Comment: this cod don't work because i have $bien['Servicebien']

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class FeedsController extends AppController {

    public $components = array( 'Search.Prg');

    public function beforeFilter() {
         parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    function indes(){
        $this->Prg->commonProcess();

        $this->{$this->modelClass}->data[$this->modelClass]         =     $this->passedArgs;
        $parsedConditions = $this->{$this->modelClass}->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs);

        $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array(),
            'limit'      => 10,
            'fields'    =>   array(),
            'order'         =>  'id DESC'    
        );        
        $result    =    $this->paginate();
    }
}
```